# Stop playing audio when clicking another audio link

Tags: javascript

I need a way to stop running audio mp3 that started from a link when clicking another audio link. I am NOYT using  tag, I am using direct href link to the audio file

This is what I have:

```html
<div id="myDIV1" style="display: block;">
<img src="newMuslims/images/SurahAl_Fatiha.jpg" width="555" height="1001" usemap="#image-map" onDblClick="imgResize(this)">
<map name="image-map">
  <area title="Aya0" href="javascript:MyAudio(0);" coords="-5,66,553,116" shape="rect">
  <area title="Ayah1"href="JavaScript:MyAudio(1);" coords="2,117,555,197" shape="rect">
  <area title="Ayah2" href="JavaScript:JavaScript:MyAudio(2);" coords="0,199,553,277" shape="rect">
  <area title="Ayah3" href="JavaScript:JavaScript:MyAudio(3);" coords="0,279,552,356" shape="rect">
  <area title="Ayah4" href="JavaScript:JavaScript:MyAudio(4);" coords="-1,358,551,481" shape="rect">
  <area title="Ayah5" href="JavaScript:JavaScript:MyAudio(5);" coords="-5,483,554,570" shape="rect">
  <area title="Ayah6" href="JavaScript:JavaScript:MyAudio(6);" coords="1,573,553,663" shape="rect">
  <area title="Ayah7" href="JavaScript:JavaScript:MyAudio(7);" coords="2,665,552,818" shape="rect">
  <area title="ameen" href="JavaScript:JavaScript:MyAudio(8);;" coords="1,820,554,913" shape="rect">
</map>
<script>
  function MyAudio(n) {
    var soundfile1 =  "https://wensite/audio/audioFile";
    var fileExt = ".mp3";
    //document.write(n);
    var num = 8;
    for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {;
      var soundfile = soundfile1.concat(i).concat(fileExt);
    }

    var soundfile = soundfile1.concat(n).concat(fileExt);
    //document.write(soundfile);
    var AyahAudio = new Audio(soundfile);
    AyahAudio.play();
  }
</script>
```

I added the following and it did not help

```html
<script>
  document.addEventListener('play', function(e) {
    var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for (var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (audios[i] != e.target) {
        audios[i].pause();
      }
    }
  }, true);
</script>
```

Please help me out, thank you

Comment: Please take the time to format the code in your question properly. I've fixed it for you in this question.

Comment: Also, you have an obvious syntax error on this line: `for (var i = 0; i <= num; i++) {;`. I would suggest you open devtools and check the console for errors.

Comment: You cannot get previous `Audio` elements from the document as you never add them to the document. That is also why the document's `play` listener does not react.

Comment: Thank you, how can i use hidden <audio> when I click the mapped area?